# List duplication performance anomaly

Tags: python, list, performance

There are 3 ways (that I know of) to duplicate a list.

Given a list L then we can do either of:

```
L[::]
list(L)
L.copy()
```

I then wondered if there was a performance benefit of using a particular technique so I decided to run some timings and determined that for a list containing some pseudo-random integers, there was no significant difference.

But then I noticed this:

```
from random import randint
from timeit import timeit

N = 100_000

a = [1] * N
b = [randint(0, 9) for _ in range(N)]

def f1(a):
    return a[::]
def f2(a):
    return a.copy()
def f3(a):
    return list(a)

for lst in a, b:
    for func in f1, f2, f3:
        print(func.__name__, timeit(lambda: func(lst), number=10_000))
```

**Output:**

```
f1 2.416802455999914
f2 2.4171504939999977
f3 2.4166464310001174
f1 1.8978477209998346
f2 1.9156776830000126
f3 1.9132091609999407
```

Thus it appears that duplicating a list containing all identical values is significantly slower than a list of the same size but with varying content.

Why would this be?

**Platform:**

```
macOS 13.5.2
Python 3.11.5
CPU 3 GHz 10-Core Intel Xeon W
RAM 32 GB 2666 MHz DDR4
```

Comment: I'm not observing difference bigger than few % after retest on my side.

Comment: @matszwecja Same Python version?

Comment: 3.11.0 although on Windows.

Comment: `[1] * N` makes a list of references, not a list of integers. It being slower might have something to do with that.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43220129/5640517) someone elses answer about speed of duplicating a list.

Comment: @Daviid I don't think that's any different with second list. Afaik Python handles everything using references.

Comment: @DarkKnight I've upgraded to 3.11.5 and the results didn't change, it's ~5.11s for `b` list and ~5.20s for `a`.

Comment: I did this test in Macos and I could see the performance difference. Not sure if it has something to do with the platform.

Comment: It seems that as N increases, the difference becomes less significant. However, even with N == 1_000_000 there's still ~12% mean difference as opposed to ~23% for N == 100_000. Very strange

Comment: I'm experiencing 3.1~4.3/1.4~2.5 with Python 3.11.5 and, surprisingly, 1.1~1.4 on Python 3.12rc2 (Windows 10). Somehow 3.12 deals with `a` much better than 3.11.

Comment: @InSync: That'd probably be [PEP 683](https://peps.python.org/pep-0683/) eliminating the refcount updates.